# How to use shared libraries in my development environment?

Tags: linux, development-environment, shared-libraries

I am working on a project with several modules. The development tree looks like:

```
/work_home/src/...
/work_home/out/bin/ <Here all the executables are built to>
/work_home/out/foo1/lib/ <one .so is built here>
/work_home/out/foo2/lib/ <another .so is built here>
...
/work_home/out/foo42/lib/ <another .so is built here>
```

Now, the following question only applies to when i am running an executable which uses the shared libraries in my development environment - as opposed to when we actually deploy our package on our customer's system.

What would be the best way to ensure that when i run an executable (from /work_home/out/bin/) it can load any shared library it needs (which is built to /work_home/out/.../lib/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`;

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/work_home/out/foo1/lib:/work_home/out/foo2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./your_executable
```

This will also look into `/work_home/out/foo1/lib` and `/work_home/out/foo2/lib` directories while resolving libraries.